# Why are no keys used in this EXPLAIN?

Tags: mysql

I was expecting this query to use a key.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE TABLE Foo;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM Foo WHERE name='foo';
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Foo has a unique index on `name`, so why isn't the index being used in the `SELECT`?

Comment: Because `WHERE` always returns false. It's in the docs.. also, let me guess, there's no record in your table matching `foo`. MySQL won't use an index for small tables because it incurs I/O penalty for no gain. It can conclude there's no such record without traversing the index.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21265

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL Manual page entitled [EXPLAIN Output Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html):

> Impossible WHERE noticed after reading **const tables** (JSON property:
>   message)
>
> MySQL has read all const (and system) tables and notice that the WHERE
>   clause is always false.

and the definition of const tables, from the Page entitled [Constants and Constant Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-constants-constant-tables.html):

> A MySQL constant is something more than a mere literal in the query.
>   It can also be the contents of a constant table, which is defined as
>   follows:
>
> A table with zero rows, or with only one row
>
> A table expression that is restricted with a WHERE condition,
>   containing expressions of the form column = constant, for all the
>   columns of the table's primary key, or for all the columns of any of
>   the table's unique keys (provided that the unique columns are also
>   defined as NOT NULL).

The second reference is a page and half long. Please refer to it.

[`const`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#jointype_const)

> const
>
> The table has at most one matching row, which is read at the start of
>   the query. Because there is only one row, values from the column in
>   this row can be regarded as constants by the rest of the optimizer.
>   const tables are very fast because they are read only once.
>
> const is used when you compare all parts of a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE
>   index to constant values. In the following queries, tbl_name can be
>   used as a const table:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE primary_key=1;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name   WHERE primary_key_part1=1 AND
>   primary_key_part2=2;

Comment: TL;DR try `where name!='foo'` to prevent the selection from being treated as a trivial single row value

Answer (score 0):

It could be because that the said table `Foo` very less volume of data. In such case optimizer will choose to do table scan rather than looking through index.

As [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) clearly says

> Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables
>   where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query
>   needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than
>   working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even
>   if not all the rows are needed for the query.

Comment: this is a different issue. The issue you describe is for small tables or high cardinality cases

Comment: @Drew, Yes but could be a possibility and most cases this is what is the reason unless the specified `WHERE` condition ends up returning no records.

Comment: I will generate an example/ imgur link to show the standard output in explain for your reference. Edit: here ya go, this is your case http://i.imgur.com/oGc0hsw.jpg