# Why if I add one more condition on WHERE clause, then using an index fails?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

Here is my query:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM qanda question
JOIN qanda answer ON question.Id = answer.related
WHERE answer.related IS NOT NULL
AND answer.author_id = 29
AND question.amount IS NULL
AND answer.id not in (
  select post_id
  from votes
  where table_code = 15
  group by post_id
  having sum(value) < 0)
```

And this is the `EXPLAIN` result of it:

[image]

As you see, all tables are using an index. Ok, now I need to add one more condition on the `WHERE` clause of outer query. This is that condition:

```
... AND from_unixtime(answer.date_time) BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL 1 year) AND (now() - INTERVAL 1 hour)
```

Well, after adding that new condition, this is the `EXPLAIN` result of it:

[image]

See? `answer` table doesn't use any index anymore. Why? And what index do I need to make query above faster and more efficient?

Comment: The premise of your conclusion that if MySQL doesn't use an index that a query would be slower. That's wrong. Sometimes it doesn't pay off to use an index - more I/O will be done than doing a table scan. As you can see, the amount of rows MySQL inspects is low. If you add an additional condition MySQL has to inspect **more** rows. It decides that using an index won't help at all so it doesn't use it. In the end, your query is fast. Add more records and test this again (something like 100 000 records or so). It'll use indexes as your data set grows (given the fact their selectivity is high).

Comment: @Drew Hah .. well I really like to write an answer for myself .. but sadly I don't have any clue `:-(` .. I even don't know why then number of *rows* which are scanned will be more when I add one more condition on the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: No your question is fine

Comment: The answer to your question, or most of it, is at the bottom of [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) right above User Comments.

Comment: @Drew Oh .. do you mean my dataset is small and I have to make a huge dataset and test that query again?

Comment: Imagine having 2 houses in a town, and a phone book (the index) on a table in front of them. And you want to know the addresses of where Smith and Jones live. And one of the homes has Smith on a plaque above the door. Going to the book then the doors is slower than using your eyes or just doing a scan.

Comment: @Drew Great example. I got the point .. and now I'm wonder how much MySQL is intelligent.

Comment: Yes. Create a dummy db then run the schema part of this answer of mine [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33666394). But stop after a few of the inserts and do an explain of like `explain select * from ratings where id=4`. When you have 11 rows, the explain shows a table scan. When you have like 1000 rows and up toward the 4.7 million, the index is used (Explain)

Comment: @Drew I see . . . . . Also +1 for your answer. `:-)`

Comment: Why thank you. Ironically it is because of N.B. that I always put the disclaimer at the top saying ignore the MyISAM part of it, and it is in no way a recommendation to ever use it. But the reason it is used in that one is because of the INNODB gap anomaly and I wanted the `max()` to equal `count()`. They didn't need to equal each other, but I was feeling OCD at that moment.

Comment: In general for questions like these, always publish the output of `show create table xyz` for every table in the query. Doing so gives us the necessary info on indexes in use. Otherwise we are blind. As for the `const` not that you asked but that is similar to [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39419835) answer maybe. The first query of yours was trucking fine with `const` until your second query made `const` uneligible and the table scan ensured due to the low row count (2 houses thing) we were just talking about. Lastly, the row count number in Explain is often a wild a** guess. Not gospel

Comment: @Drew Ah I see .. ok .. next time I'll attach more detail of my database structure to the question.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Dup of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149320/why-if-i-add-one-more-condition-on-where-clause-then-using-an-index-fails .

Comment: Stack you rascal don't cross post

Comment: @Drew ok .. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Using index" implies that the index is "covering".  That is, *all* the columns (from that table) that are needed for the query are in that composite index.  It appears that `answer` has `INDEX(author_id, related, id)`.  Hence, the best approach is to use the index BTree and ignore the Data BTree.

When you added a condition on `date_time`, and that column was not part of the *same* index, the query might be run one of these ways:

- Look in the index's BTree, then reach over to the data to check the `date_time`.  Repeat.
- Ignore the index and simply scan the data.

The cutoff between the two choices varies with the phase of the moon, but typically is somewhere around 20%.  The `EXPLAIN` implies that it chose the latter approach.  (*See Drew's excellent analogy!*)

Change the index to `INDEX(author_id, date_time, related, id)` (in *that* order) *and* change the new where clause to

```
AND datetime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
AND datetime  < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

This index will still be "covering", so it should continue to be "Using index".  The order of columns is: (1) check for equality, (2) check a range, then whatever other columns are needed for 'covering'.

This index will be not quite as good for the original query, but it will still be 'covering'.

The change to the `WHERE` is to avoid "hiding" the column `date_time` inside a function, which prevents the use of an index.

Comment: Why do you think using both `>=` and `<` is better than `BETWEEN`?

Comment: `BETWEEN` id identical to `>=` and `<=` in performance and effect.  When doing date ranges, I prefer `>=` and `<` so that I don't inadvertently pick up midnight at both ends.