# MySQL : Using EXPLAIN keyword to know about indexing. (Specific Use Case)

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, explain

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `channel_play_times_bar_chart` (
  `playing_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `channel_report_tag` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `device_report_tag` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `greater_than_30_minutes` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `15_to_30_minutes` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `0-15_minutes` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`,`device_report_tag`,`channel_report_tag`,`playing_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I run the following query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT 
  channel_report_tag,
  SUM(`greater_than_30_minutes`) AS '>30 minutes',
  SUM(`15_to_30_minutes`) AS '15-30 Minutes',
  SUM(`0-15_minutes`) AS '0-15 Minutes' 
FROM
  channel_play_times_bar_chart USE INDEX (ABCDE) 
WHERE country_code = 'US' 
  AND device_report_tag = 14 
  AND channel_report_tag = 'DUNYA NEWS' 
  AND playing_date BETWEEN '2016-09-01' 
  AND '2016-09-13' 
GROUP BY channel_report_tag 
ORDER BY SUM(`greater_than_30_minutes`) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

This is the output I get ( open it in another tab):

[image: result set]

The **index** was defined as :

```
CREATE INDEX ABCDE 
ON channel_play_times_bar_chart (
  `country_code`,
  `device_report_tag`,
  `channel_report_tag`,
  `playing_date`,
  `greater_than_30_minutes`
)
```

**I am a bit confused here ; The `key` column shows ABCDE being used the as the `index` , yet `ref` column shows `NULL`. What does this mean ? Is the index actually being used ? If not what did I do wrong ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is using the key you are showing in the `create index`, that is, `ABCDE`.
It would be nice if you did a

```
show create table channel_play_times_bar_chart
```

and just showed it all at once. That key might not be of much use to you as it replicates most of what your rather wide Primary Key already gives you.

Once the query uses the key up thru the 3rd segment of the composite key, it resumes with a `WHERE` range on `playing_date` in that composite and finds 8 rows.

Note `EXPLAIN` is an estimate.

Further, I would reconsider the strategy for your `PRIMARY KEY` (`PK`) ideas especially considering that you decided to dupe it up more or less with the creation of `ABCDE`. That means you are maintaining two indexes with little if anything gained on the second one (you added one column to the secondary index `ABCDE`).

The `PK` It is rather WIDE (118 bytes I believe). It dictates the physical ordering. And that idea could easily be a bad one if used throughout the way you architect things. Changes made to data via `UPDATE` that impact the columns in the `PK` force a reshuffle of physical ordering of the table. That fact would be a good indication why `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` is often used as a best practice use case as it never endures a reshuffle and is THIN (4 bytes).

The width of keys and their strategy with *referencing* (other) tables (in Foreign Key Constraints) impact key sizes and performance for lookups. Wide keys can measurably slow down that process.

This is not to suggest that you shouldn't have a key on those columns like your secondary index `ABCDE`. But in general that is not a good idea for the `PK`.

Note that it could be argued that `ABCDE` never gives you *any* benefit over your PK due to range queries ceasing the use of it near the end that just `WHERE` out with ranges once it hits the date. Just a thought.

A nice read and rather brief is the article [Using EXPLAIN to Write Better MySQL Queries](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/).

Comment: As far as the `const` comment to Shadow, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39419835

Comment: What if I replace the PK with unique key ? Will it help as in to the over all architecture and that shuffling thing? And yes I'm just dealing with only one table, no references.

Comment: A PK is a unique key. Just strive to make them thin and non-changing.

Comment: Your post is too informational for a beginner like me. Wish could have given you another up-vote. Thanks ! . Points to be noted are that indexing is working and  PK should be as this as possible ? right ?

Comment: Indexing is working. Problem is that you have virtually 2 indexes with no added benefit in the secondary which you force with the use of `USE INDEX (ABCDE)`. Not earth shattering on smaller tables. On huge tables ditch unneeded and non-used indexes. PK should be thin. So, what I would do is have your PK an int as described, and have your `ABCDE`. But note, index choices are governed by the full array of all your queries. Not just one. Choose them for impact on your main / often / bread and butter queries that mean the most to your end users.

Comment: One last question, what do you mean by the PK being "non-changing"

Comment: `id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` never changes (unless some wise guy like me says yeah wanna bet? I can make that change watch me). But practically speaking they don't. A `PK` that has components in a composite like `ABCDE` in many cases *do* change with `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: @Drew - For a table with no secondary keys, adding a 'thin' auto-increment actually hurts performance.  In that case, it is better to have a 'wide' PK and no 'id'.  OTOH, it hurts to have a frequently changing column included in any index.

Comment: @RickJames I was never suggesting not to have the secondary and just a thin PK

Answer (score 1):

Your query does use the `ABCDE` index. As MySQL documentation on [EXPLAIN Output Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) explains :) (bolding is mine):

> key (JSON name: key)
>
> The key column indicates the key (index) that MySQL actually **decided
>   to use**. If MySQL decides to use one of the possible_keys indexes to
>   look up rows, that index is listed as the key value.

The `ref` field of the explain output is primarily used when joins are present to show the fields / constants / expressions the index was compared with.

Comment: Actually what worries me is that when I change  "playing_date BETWEEN '2016-09-01' AND '2016-09-13' " to ""playing_date = ''2016-09-13 " , the ref column fills up with "const, const, const, const". Why is that ?

Comment: Because you will have 4 constants in your where criteria in this case. These constants are used to compare the index columns' values with.

Comment: why doesn't it show "const, const, const, const" when I use BETWEEN ?

Comment: @DanishBinSofwan because as shown in my comment section, comment one link, a const: "The table has at most one matching row". And that does not happen with a `BETWEEN` range.